# Where/How can I find law abiding non-lawyers to provide high-quality information and assistance for pursuing a California arbitration case?

Tags: california, legal-research, arbitration, attorney-fees, alternative-dispute-resolution

The reason for choosing a non-lawyer rather than a lawyer is to reduce fees.

Comment: Why do you think a competent ADR professional will be cheaper than a lawyer? I’m certainly not.

Answer (score 1):

One common type of assistant you can use is called a legal document assistant.  You can find LDA's on [CALDA's website](https://calda.org/page-18152).  To narrow down your choices you can choose Mediation from the LDA Services column.